# Why do images loaded to texture with IMG_Load in SDL and OpenGL look bluish?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, photoshop, sdl-image

I'm loading a PNG texture with:

```
void Sprite::setTexture(string f) {
    SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load(f.c_str());
    if (image == NULL) {
        this->texture = -1;
        return;
    }
    SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha(image);
    unsigned object(0);
    glGenTextures(1, &object);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, object);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image->w, image->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    this->texture = object;
}
```

The only problem is that instead of being like this (seen in Photoshop):

[image: Original box]

it is shown like this (seen in the app):

What's wrong? I have tried playing a little bit with tha GL_RGBA and tried to invert it to GL_BGRA or change it to GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA16... but nothing changed (actually GL_BGRA didn't show anything). I need the alpha channel, even in this little PNG the borders are radius at 4px and so the image angles are transparent.

What am I doing wrong?
[image: App box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely looks like your channels are inverted. It's hard to see from here if your alpha is working properly, but some textures are `ARGB`, maybe you should try that!

Actually, just to validate your data, you should check your

```
SDL_Surface *image
```

And see what's `image->format->Rmask` `Gmask` `Bmask` and `Amask`, this way you can be sure what format your surface has.

Comment: Actually I retried `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image->w, image->h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);` and it worked. I have had probably set a different internal format last time. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeffrey I'm not sure if your comment means you found out how to convert your surface or not?